# Distributing value of variable to specific kernel

Tags: parallelization

I want to distribute the value of a variable to a specific kernel in a parallel computing setup. Using `DistributeDefinitions` of course does the job, but it distributes the value to every active kernel, which is unnecessary and takes too much time.
In my case I do have an array `a` and a listable function `f` operating on this array. A simple test scenario would be:

```
a = Table[Random[],{i,1000}];
f[x_] = x^2;
```

now I want to manually split up this calculation so that that each kernel has the same amounts of function calls to `f`, which would look schematically like this (I assume 1000/$KernelCount is an Integer):

```
handle = {};
For[i = 1, i <= $KernelCount, i++, 
      AppendTo[handle, 
       ParallelSubmit[{i}, f[a[[(i - 1)*1000/$KernelCount + 1 ;; i*1000/$KernelCount]]]]
   ];
];
test = WaitAll[handle];
```

Of course this does not work, because the kernels do not have any knowledge about `a`. I could use `DistributeDefinitions[a]`. But this is as mentioned before exactly what I do not want to, because each kernel only has to know about a certain part of `a`, so distributing the whole array `a` would be a waste of time. This is of course only a test scenario, the real scenario consists of way more data bundled in the array `a` and a more complicated function `f`, but the task remains the same.
I thought of using `ParallelEvaluate` to distribute part i of `a` to kernel i, but I did not come up with a solution. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round 2:

```
test=WaitAll[
  Table[(b=a[[(i1)*1000/$KernelCount+1;;i*1000/$KernelCount]];
         ParallelSubmit[{b},(Pause[1.0];$KernelID->f[b])]),
            {i,1,$KernelCount}]];
```

Inside Table chop out the bit of a you want to send to a specific Kernel and place in b.  Pass b as a closure into ParallelSubmit rather than i.  Apply f to b within the parallel evaluation.  Note the Pause is just to force a different Kernel each time because this test case is so fast without it $KernelID (just to show which Kernel is being used) would (in my case) always be 1.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I can't explain why I did not see that in the first place, but whatever :).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use ParallelMap and let it sort out which bits of a to send to each kernel?

And example...

```
a = Range[100]
```

Create a local store in each kernel to demonstrate which parts of a arrive....

```
ParallelEvaluate[z = {}];
```

Now execute...

```
ParallelMap[f, a];
```

Now check each z in each kernel...

```
ParallelEvaluate[z]

{{33,34,35,36,65,66,67,68,97,98,99,100},
{29,30,31,32,61,62,63,64,93,94,95,96},
{25,26,27,28,57,58,59,60,89,90,91,92},
{21,22,23,24,53,54,55,56,85,86,87,88},
{16,17,18,19,20,49,50,51,52,81,82,83,84},
{11,12,13,14,15,45,46,47,48,77,78,79,80},
{6,7,8,9,10,41,42,43,44,73,74,75,76},
{1,2,3,4,5,37,38,39,40,69,70,71,72}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not an option in my more complicated case, that would have taken way longer to explain. Essential is that I need a solution to the problem above because I cannot use ParallelMap. Short version is that in my case f is a listable compiled function and the real parallelism takes place on the compiled level.

Comment: Is a too big to distribute a copy of it to all kernels?

Comment: Essentially my compiled function f does not take very long to compute, but I think long enough to benefit from parallization. If I distributing the whole data array to all kernels takes about as long as calculating the function on a single multicore machine, but if I could split up the data array and only distribute a small fraction I guess the scenario could benefit from parallel computing especially if there are many machines in the distibuted computing cluster.